# Wildfly 10 slow startup

Tags: wildfly, startup, wildfly-10, application-server

I have Wildfly 10.1.0 and when I start it from command line it takes about 30 seconds to start up. When I start it from inside Eclipe it takes instead about 1 minute.

In **Eclipse** the first long pause (about 30 seconds) is taken after the line:

```
 [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 32 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
```

The second long pause (another 30 seconds) is taken while in the bottom right corner appears the message:

```
Checking Deployment Scanners for server
```

In the **command line** the first long pause (about 20 seconds) is taken after the line:

```
[org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 128 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
```

The second "long" pause (about 10 seconds) is taken after the line:

```
[org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
```

So the question is: how do I remove/reduce the above mentioned pauses, especially those in Eclipse? Thanks.

Comment: Can you do thread dump while this pause is happening?

Comment: I switched off the computer, moved today to another place and now the server starts up in 3 seconds from both Eclipse and command line. I don't know if it can be the pc shut down and restart or the change of the internet connection...